# NOT operator of this statement in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Doing some stuff in the touches method in my project. I typically set up my touches methods like so:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location: CGPoint = touch.location(in: self)
    }
}
```

Then I just check to see if the touches are contained in the node:

```
if myNode.contains(location) {
    // Do stuff in here
}
```

What is the NOT version of this if-statement?

Pseudo-code:

```
if myNode does not contain(location) {
    // Do other stuff in here
}
```

I can't find this version and the Apple Docs don't have anything to say about this.

Comment: `if myNode.contains(location) == false {`? `if !myNode.contains(location) {`?

Comment: `if !myNode.contains(location){ }`

Comment: ‍♂️ I tried the `!` operator out front and got an error. It was part of an AND statement. Just tried it again and didn't get an error. Possibly a bug?

Comment: What was the exact statement that gave you an error?

Comment: Most of the time you get an error it's a programmer mistake and not a bug ;)

Comment: The exact statement was `if isTracking == false && !myNode.contains(location) { }`

Comment: @E.Huckabee There was probably a typo on your side, e.g. a space between `!` and `myNode` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Any thing that goes into else is a NOT version.

Now if if understand your problem correctly, you have a touchable sprite, if that is touched you want to perform an action otherwise second action. Hence in case of else you can write that second action.

If this is not the case then please let us know the specific problem so I can suggest a more appropriate solution.

Comment: More specifically, I want something to happen if that sprite does not contain the touches.

Comment: That's what I assumed. So write that stuff in else.

Answer (score 0):

`myNode` can't be negated with `!`, you can only negate a boolean:

```
if !(myNode.contains(location)) {
    // Do stuff in here
}
```